# Java: Large collection and concurrent threads

Tags: java, concurrency, multithreading

I am  facing this issue:
I have lots of threads (1024) who access one large collection - Vector.
Question:
is it possible to do something about it which would allow me to do concurrent actions on it without having to synchronize everything (since that takes time)? What I mean, is something like Mysql database works, you don't have to worry about synchronizing and thread-safe issues. Is there some collection alike that in Java? Thanks

Comment: Why do you have 1024 threads? That's crazy.

Comment: I have 8 core CPU and 8 gb RAM, and 3000 users accessing my application, so I think that's okay, no?

Comment: @Mark: Not necessarily, it's just a very high degree of concurrency. However, 1024 threads on 8 cores is probably excessive.

Comment: Are the threads doing modifications to the Vector or just reading from it?  Once the threads start to do their operations is the size of the vector going to change? The set-lock model Java uses will be the problem but there are ways to design your application to be threadsafe without these steps.

Comment: I suggest getting yourself a copy of Java Concurrency in Practice

Comment: all what thread does is adding elements to vector (only if num of elements in vector = 0) & removing elements from vector. (if vector size > 0)

Comment: Wait... are these threads treating your Vector like a queue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vector is a very old Java class - predates the Collections API.  It synchronizes on every operation, so you're not going to have any luck trying to speed it up.
You should consider reworking your code to use something like ConcurrentHashMap or a LinkedBlockingQueue, which are highly optimized for concurrent access.

Failing that, you mention that you'd like performance and access semantics similar to a database - why not use a dedicated database or a message queue?  They are likely to implement it better than you ever will, and it's less code for you to write!

[edit] Given your comment:

```
all what thread does is adding elements to vector 
(only if num of elements in vector = 0) & 
removing elements from vector. (if vector size > 0)
```

it sounds very much like you should be using something much more like a queue than a list!  A bounded queue with size 1 will give you these semantics - although I'd question why you can't add elements if there is already something there.  When you've got thousands of threads this seems like a very inefficient design.

Answer (score 5):

Well first off, this design doesn't sound right. It sounds like you need to think about using a proper database rather than an simple data structure, even if this means just using something like an in-memory instance of [HypersonicDB](http://hsqldb.org/).

However, if you insist on doing things this way, then the [java.util.concurrent](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) package has a number of highly concurrent, non-locking data structures. One of them might suit your purpose (e.g. [ConcurrentHashMap](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html), if you can use a `Map` rather than a `List`)

Comment: -1: Considering his comment about the usage of the Vector, I think Steven Schlansker's answer about considering a queue is much more appropriate.

Comment: You downvote an answer if you think it's a bad one, not because you think another answer is better.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are implementing the producer consumer pattern, you should google "producer consumer java" or have a look at [the BlockingQueue interface](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with skaffman about looking at java.util.concurrent.

ConcurrentHashMap is very scalable. However, the size() call on it returns only an approximation. So e.g. your app will occasionally be adding elements to it even if !(num of elements in vector = 0).

If you want to strictly enforce the condition you gave, there is no other way than to synchronize.

Instead of having tons of context switches, I guess you could let your users thread post a callable on a queue and have only one thread dealing with the mutation. This will eliminate the need for synchronization on the collection. The user threads can wait on Future.get().

Just an idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to change your data structure and have only infrequent writes, you might also use one or many [ReentrantReadWriteLock](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html) to synchronize access. Then many threads can read at the same time, but when a thread wants to write all reads are blocked until the write is done.

But you should check whether the used data structure is appropriate for the task, or whether another of the many java.util or java.util.concurrent classes is more appropriate. java.util.Vector *is* synchronized, by the way.